# Laravel Livewire: All Methods are executed twice

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a super weird issue in my project, and I'm trying to isolate the issue since 2 days and I can't find out why it happens and more important how to prevent it.
**All methods in Livewire components are executed twice. Looks like they are executed almost at the same time**

It seems like livewire is running twice in the backend. In most cases I don't even realize that the methods are executed twice. I can do even easy onclick counters that work as expected,but if I save a new instance of a model, I get 2 new identical models (apart from ID) and if I send out emails the email is sent out twice.

Here is what I tried and checked:

1. click event sends only one request to the server.
2. building click counters (public property on Component) into the method that's called -> it counts up once
3. it seems that the method is running twice at the same time with the same values.
4. I reinstalled Livewire and updated to latest Version 2.10 -> no difference
5. stripping back everything to a minimum with nothing in the view but the essentials -> same result

```
<html>
  <head>
    @livewireStyles
  </head>
  <body>
    <livewire:test.simple-class />
    @livewireScripts
  </body>
</html>
```

My component

```
class SimpleClass extends Component
{
    public $counter = 0;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test.simple-class');
    }


    public function clickMe()
    {
        $this->counter ++;
        $admin = Auth::user();
        $admin->notify(new SimpleNotification($admin, "Clicking in simple test field"));
    }
}
```

The view of the component

```
<div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" wire:click='clickMe'>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
    {{$counter}}
</div>
```

6. The issue is not local, as I have exactly the same behavior on the production server.
7. On a fresh Laravel installation on the same local server the same Scenario works great -> One click count + 1 email
8. I also deleted the vendors folder and run composer install -> no difference

Please help!

Comment: What does the view you have look like?

Comment: @Qirel Post updated

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it, by following the request the click event sends to the server. It's quite an old project and it has been updated many times and it appears I had an "error" in one of the middlewares: `VerifyCsrfToken`

After changing the lines, which I don't even remember why we've put it in there, the Livewire methods where executed only once.

**Old:**

```
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        parent::handle($request, $next);
        unset($request['_token']);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**New:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        unset($request['_token']);
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
```